# How to access this encapsulated value?

Tags: node.js

I am using a method wich belongs to a module as a callback in a function from my server.

From this method, i need to access an array encasulated in the module (`MyArray`).

I can't use `this` since it refers to the original function (`someFunction` in my example).
But i don't understand why i can't use the `that: this` feature in this case (`that is undefined`).

**MyModule.js**

```
module.exports = {
  MyArray: [],
  that: this,
  test: functiion() {
    //How to access MyArray ?
  }
};
```

**server.js**

```
var MyModule = require('MyModule');
someFunction(MyModule.test);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.MyArray` works.

`MyModule.test` is bound to a `this` equal to `module.exports`

You can also just use local variables inside your module.

#### MyModule.js

```
var MyArray = [];

module.exports = {
  test: function() {
    // MyArray is accessible
  }
};
```

And you could also use `module.exports.MyArray`.

Comment: You are aware of that inner functions returned from the module have access by closure to MyArray

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the `this` you want to that function so that even when it's used as a callback the `this` is correct:

**MyModule.js**

```
module.exports = {
  MyArray: []
};
module.exports.test = (function() {
  console.log(this.MyArray); // works here even when not called via MyModule.test
}).bind(module.exports);
```